# \textit generates different shape from primary italic font

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, italic

It's said that `\textit` will select an italic font, instead of doing some geographical change to the font. This means it will generate exactly the same thing as using italic font directly. However, I found it strange when using `\textit` because it generates something different from the original italic font.

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\avr{Avenir Next Regular}[Ligatures=TeX]
\newfontfamily\avd{Avenir Next Demi Bold}[Ligatures=TeX]
\newfontfamily\avdi{Avenir Next Demi Bold Italic}[Ligatures=TeX]
\begin{document}
\section{}
{\avd This is "Avenir Next Demi Bold" font.}
\section{}
{\avdi This is "Avenir Next Demi Bold Italic" font.}
\section{}
\textit{\avd{This is textit\{"Avenir Next Demi Bold" font.\}}}
\section{}
\avr Why the last two have different ``boldness''?
\end{document}
```

[image: difference shown in the picture]

Obviously 2 and 3 are different. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: It can happen. Font names are not exact, they differ often from font to font and so the heuristic to identify  italic or bold can fail.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So I should directly use the italic font?

Comment: Use the ItalicFont key to setup the italic font, see the fontspec documentation.

Comment: You probably want `\newfontface` instead of `\newfontfamily`.

Comment: you have declared your three fonts as new families so (to latex/fontspec) they are just unrelated fonts avdi has not been declared as the italic version of avd.

Comment: I can just try and guess that you have some “Avenir Next Bold Italic” font. Thus `\newfontfamily{\avd}{Avenir Next Demi Bold}` will try to make a whole font family from the declaration, hence choosing the (non Demi) version for bold and bold italic.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Year, you are right. So how should I relate them together (how do I let latex know that \avdi is the italic version of \avd)?